# Re.match() returns always none

Tags: python, regex

I feel kind of stupid but it does not work:

```
import re

a = " ebrj wjrbw erjwek wekjb rjERJK ABB RAEJKE BWE RWEJBEWJ B KREWBJ BWERBJ32J3B23B J BJ235JK BJJ523 2"

print re.match(ur'/(wekjb|ABB)/',a)
if re.match(ur'/(wekjb|ABB)/',a):
    print 'success'
```

I have the `ur'` if the user given `a` is unicode. I want to print success if `wekjb` or `ABB` is in the string but I always get `None` as the result of the `match`.

Comment: Try using `.search()` instead of `.match()`.  `.match()` is anchored to the start of the string.  And there are no instances of `/` in `a` - why are there instances of `/` in your regexp?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) is implicitly anchored to the start of the string.  If you want to search a string for a substring that can be anywhere within it, then you need to use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import re

a = " ebrj wjrbw erjwek wekjb rjERJK ABB RAEJKE BWE RWEJBEWJ B KREWBJ BWERBJ32J3B23B J BJ235JK BJJ523 2"

print re.search(ur'(wekjb|ABB)',a).group()
if re.search(ur'(wekjb|ABB)',a):
    print 'success'
```

Output:

```
wekjb
success
```

Also, Python Regexes do not need to have a `/` at the start and end.

Lastly, I added `.group()` to the end of the `print` line because I think this is what you want.  Otherwise, you'd get something like `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01812220>`, which isn't too useful.

Comment: I don't think it's the case that "`re.match` looks for an _exact_ match." Rather, it's that `match()` is implicitely anchored at the beginning of line. But maybe I'm just dicing semantics there..?  The expression `ur'.*(wekjb|ABB)',a` works just fine.

Comment: @TravisGriggs - No, that's fine.  It's better to be technical.  I adjusted my post and added a link for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of that `match` method returns `None` if it couldn't find expected pattern, if it find the pattern it would return an object with type of `_sre.SRE_match` .

So, if you want Boolean (`True` or `False`) result from `match` you must check the result is `None` or not!

You could examine texts is matched or not somehow like this:

```
string_to_evaluate = "Your text that needs to be examined"
expected_pattern = "pattern"

if re.match(expected_pattern, string_to_evaluate) is not None:
    print("The text is as you expected!")
else:
    print("The text is not as you expected!")
```