# Storing Python RegEx multiple groups

Tags: python, regex, multiple-matches

I'm webscraping a site using python. The returned results have the following format, ( https://regex101.com/r/irr14u/10 ), where everything works ok apart from the last occassion  where i get 2 matches for the dates (1st match:Thur.-Sun., Tue., Wed. and second match: Mon.)

I'm using the following code to get the values that i want. I use BeautifoulSoup to get movieDate string, but here i hardcoded it.

```
movieDate="Thur.-Sun., Tue., Wed.: 20.50/ 23.00, Mon. 23.00"

weekDays=re.match(',? *(?P<weekDays>[^\d:\n]+):? *(?P<startTime>[^,\n]+)', movieDate).groupdict()['weekDays']
startTime=re.match(',? *(?P<weekDays>[^\d:\n]+):? *(?P<startTime>[^,\n]+)', movieDate).groupdict()['startTime']
```

I want to create a dictionary as following (it has two keys because the are two startTime values);
The first key will be Thur.-Sun., Tue., Wed. with value =20.50/ 23.00
and the second key will be Mon. with value=23:00.
There might be occassions with one or more than two keys. So the dictionary will be as following;

```
dictionary={ Thur.-Sun., Tue., Wed.: 20.50/ 23.00, Mon.: 23.00}
```

Any suggestions to achieve that in a non boggy way?

Comment: Can you provide details on where you are stuck and how things work?

Comment: I dont know how to create the dictionary and especially how to get the multiple regex matches

Comment: Can you provide a minimal complete verifiable example? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output using `finditer` function, appending result of the captured groups to a dict dynamically.

Python snippet:

```
import re
movieDate = """
Thur.-Sun., Tue., Wed.: 20.50/ 23.00, Mon. 23.00
"""

d = dict();
r = re.compile(',? *(?P<weekDays>[^\d:\n]+):? *(?P<startTime>[^,\n]+)')
for m in r.finditer(movieDate):
    d[m.group(1)] = m.group(2)

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'Thur.-Sun., Tue., Wed.': '20.50/ 23.00', 'Mon. ': '23.00'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked fine. Another thing i want to ask is; weekDays=re.match(',? *(?P<weekDays>[^\d:\n]+):? *(?P<startTime>[^,\n]+)', movieDate).groupdict()['weekDays'] prints only first match, how i have to modify it to print all the matches?

Comment: You are welcome, I believe that is because `re.match` is anchored at the beginning of the string. An alternative is to `re.search` instead. You may refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19871308/3390419) for more details.